# Pharo (SmallTalk) dont open Windows 8

Tags: exe, windows-8.1, smalltalk, pharo

I am having a problem with all the (portable, mountable, etc. ..) versions of Pharo (2.0).
I have a PC with Windows 8.1 (Desktop x64) and when trying to open Pharo I get the menu parameters to run it (see picture).
This is the portable version of Pharo who is in a Dropbox folder, and open the same exe from another PC (notebook) and runs well.
Pharo open right from the "sh" in Ubuntu, in this machine (desktop x64) and the notebook.

The problem persists if I download new / clean versions via Web of Pharo.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the machine who I use Pharo (Notebook with Windows 7) is in the Dropbox folder (C:/Users/MyUser/Dropbox/Pharo). And it is the same directory as the desktop PC (Windows 8.1).

But I think I found what the problem is. When Pharo opened from the desktop (C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/Pharo) did not walk, but when I ran from disk (C:/Pharo) **worked well**.
After I opened it from another disk folder (C:/AnyFolder/Pharo) and also worked.
But I went back to put it in user folder and didnt works (C:/Users/MyUser/Documents).
So **the problem is the name of the folder "MyUser" *(userfolder)***.
The userfolder in my PC has a tilde (ascento is Spanish) because it is a Spanish name.
I affirm that this is the problem because I created a folder with accent on the disk (C:/fólder/Pharo) and did not work.

And the problem has no solution but to change the name of the user folder. And is a little hard work.

Thank you.

**"Solved" Problem...**

Comment: Just a few years late :-) : you might also try using the short name for the folder. Windows creates a "short" name for folders with long names or unusual characters in them, which you can see from the command prompt by using the `dir /x` command. For example, in my home directory I have a folder named `.lein`, and because it has a period in the name Windows generates a "short" name of `LEIN~1`. You can use the short names to replace the long directory name in any directory path.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what's in the Pharo.ini file as this is what is pointing to the image.

```
[Global]
DeferUpdate=1
ShowConsole=0
DynamicConsole=1
ReduceCPUUsage=1
ReduceCPUInBackground=0
3ButtonMouse=0
1ButtonMouse=0
UseDirectSound=1
PriorityBoost=1
B3DXUsesOpenGL=0
CaseSensitiveFileMode=0
ImageFile=Contents\Resources\Pharo2.0-portable.image
```

Check the read/write status of the folder and files for the current user.

Are you running from a network drive? With a UNC path?

I just downloaded here on a Windows 8.1 x64 box and it works from a local folder.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities to distinguish between are whether it is:
* some different machine 
* running from the dropbox folder

Can you try copying it out of the dropbox folder to somewhere else on your C: drive?

Does the working machine have Pharo in a dropbox folder?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the Pharo Launcher http://www.smalltalkhub.com/#!/~Pharo/PharoLauncher